# Find and remove all child rows of table where attribute is undefined

Tags: jquery

How to find all rows of a table where attribute `[data-order]` is undefined?

```
this.tbl_list[0].rows.find('[data-order="undefined"]').remove();
```

this returns:

```
this.tbl_list[0].rows.find is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rows` is a DOM property, not a jQuery object so you can't call `.find()` on it.

So try this:

```
$(this.tbl_list[0].rows).find(':not[data-order]').remove();
```

(and thanks to other answers about reversing the test, since `undefined` won't work in an attribute selector)

Answer (score 0):

You can negate the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
this.table_list[0].find('td:not([data-order])').remove();
```

**Edit** - this is for rows which don't have the `data-order` attribute. If you want to search for the actual value 'undefined', go with @Alnitak's answer.

Comment: if `table_list[0]` is a DOM element he still can't call `.find()` on it.